# Tagging of names, revisited

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

About three years ago, in the early days of HSM, [it was decided](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/tagging-of-names) on meta that it was probably not useful to tag posts by the names of relevant scientists. The reason for this is that it would lead to a huge amount of tags which would only be used once, or a handful of times, which only causes cluttering and doesn't really serve much of a purpose.

However, the most highly-upvoted answer to that old question does mention the possibility of creating some exceptions to this rule. I think it is now time to try to make our policy more concrete/clear.

1. Do we want to allow *any* "name tags"? What exactly is the reason we do/do not (some arguments *against* have been given in the answer to the linked question)?
2. a) If yes, how do we decide which scientists get a name tag?

   b) If yes, what formatting do we use for the name tags? [firstname-lastname](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firstname-lastname), or does [lastname](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lastname) suffice?

   c)  If yes, I propose to use this thread to maintain a list of those scientists who have their own name tag (for future reference, e.g. when justifying the removal of *other* name tags).

Answer (score 5):

I have a very utilitarian view of tagging. A tag that's applied to only one question may describe the question accurately, but it's probably not very helpful for organizing the site. A rule of thumb I like to use: could people reasonably be expected to have a particular interest or expertise in the work of the tag topic (i.e. scientist) in question, and therefore want to "follow" or "favorite" the tag? If so, create it; if not, don't.

Regarding formatting, I would suggest using whatever communicates the meaning/intent of the tag best, rather than applying a one-size-fits-all format. I can think of only a single famous Lavoisier, and a single famous Mendeleev. People (especially new users) will instinctively be looking for an "Einstein" tag, not an "Albert-Einstein" tag. Last name is probably enough there. On the other hand, Curie on its own may not be; the question is *probably* about Marie, but it could be about Pierre. And with [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_family), forget about it. In those cases, you might want firstname-lastname.